# Split this csv/xls into separate files based on two columns?

Tags: excel, bash, csv, split, kettle

I have a 35 MB Excel file with these columns:

```
Index, Name, Year, AgeGroup1, AgeGroup2, AgeGroup3 [...]
1, Sweden, 1950, 20, 25, 27
2, Norway, 1950, 22, 27, 28
2, Sweden, 1951, 24, 24, 22
```

I'd like to split the file into several csv files based on the "Name" column (and preferably also name the files based on the value in this column).
I'd also like the files to be sorted by "Year" (but this could of course be done in Excel beforehand.)

A bash script or Kettle/Pentaho solution would be much appreciated. (Alternatives are also welcome.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just used the example data you pasted there.

awk oneliner can do it for you:

```
 awk -F, 'NR==1{title=$0;next} { print >> ($2".csv");colse}' yourCSV
```

see below test:

```
kent$  l  
total 4.0K
-rw-r--r-- 1 kent kent 136 2011-10-05 11:04 t

kent$  cat t
Index, Name, Year, AgeGroup1, AgeGroup2, AgeGroup3
1, Sweden, 1950, 20, 25, 27
2, Norway, 1950, 22, 27, 28
2, Sweden, 1951, 24, 24, 22


kent$  awk -F, 'NR==1{title=$0;next} { print >> $2".csv"}' t

kent$  head *.csv
==>  Norway.csv <==
2, Norway, 1950, 22, 27, 28

==>  Sweden.csv <==
1, Sweden, 1950, 20, 25, 27
2, Sweden, 1951, 24, 24, 22
```

**update**

```
 awk -F, 'NR>1{ fname=$2".csv"; print >>(fname); close(fname);}' yourCsv
```

Comment: Two comments: 1. In awk, in most situations, you don't need double >> to append. In this case, you don't. 2. Using redirection without parenthesis is not portable (some awk implementations get confused).

Comment: @Dimitre Radoulov: Thanks for your script. It however gives this error: "awk: illegal statement at source line 1".

Comment: @dani, which operating system and *awk* version are you using? Could you post the exact command you're running?

Comment: @Dimitre Radoulov: Dear Dimitre, I put this in a .sh file: awk -F, 'NR==1{title=$0;next} { print > $2".csv"}' clean_1950_2100_TEST.csv. I'm running Mac OS 10.6 with awk version 20070501. Thanks.

Comment: @dani, this is not my code :) Anyway, to fix the error you'll need to change `print > $2".csv"` to `print > ($2".csv")`.

Comment: @Dimitre Radoulov: Oups, my fault ... I still however don't get it to output the whole bunch of CSV files ... Now using: awk -F, 'NR==1{title=$0;next} { print > ($2".csv")}' test.csv

Comment: @Dimitre Radoulov: How can I close the files not to have too many open?

Answer (score 0):

If awk is acceptable, export to *csv* and run the following command:

```
awk -F, '{
  print > ($2 ".csv") 
  }' OFS=, infile.csv
```

Report back if you:

1. Want to preserve the header line in all files.
2. Get errors because of too many open files.

To sort the file outside of Excel:

```
sort -t, -k3,3n infile.csv | awk ...
```

Edit: This will take care of most of the issues (except for the concurrently open files):

```
{
  read
  printf '%s\n' "$REPLY"
  sort -bt, -k3,3
  } < infile | 
    awk -F', *' 'NR == 1 {
      h = $0; next
      }
    {
      f = $2 ".csv"
      if (!_[f]++) 
        print h > f 
      print > f 
      }' OFS=', '
```

If you hit the "too many open files" limit of your awk implementation,
you could use something like this:

```
awk -F, 'NR > 1 { 
  if (f) close (f)
  f = $2 ".csv"
  print > f
  }' OFS=, infile
```

Comment: If we close(f), then we do need ">>" otherwise you only get one line in each file. (the last line)

Comment: Hi @Kent, yes in that case we need double >>.